# How to make universal cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

How would I make cookie that can be accesed by any website in javascript? Or how can I make a cookie that can be accesed by any website that has my domain name?

Comment: [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason to use cookies, I would use localStorage. It is easy to use and can either be accessed by the domain name or the web browsers themselves. Also localStorage has a bigger memory then cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That would violate browser security.